# Wilcards not working for XQuery assertions in SoapUI

Tags: xpath, groovy, xquery, soapui, assertions

This is the response for one of my test steps:

```
   <Names>
        <NameList PropertyName="Record">
           <Names>
              <SimpleValue Value=" Date: MM/DD/Year "/>
              <SimpleValue Value="Name: John "/>
              <SimpleValue Value="Amount: 1234"/>
              <SimpleValue Value="Change: 2.0 "/>
              <SimpleValue Value="Total: 0.0 "/>
           </Names>
        </NameList>
   </Names>
```

I'm expecting the exact match in my Xquery assertion except the value where it says total.

This is what my assertion looks like:

```
       <Names>
        <NameList PropertyName="Record">
           <Names>
              <SimpleValue Value=" Date: MM/DD/Year "/>
              <SimpleValue Value="Name: John "/>
              <SimpleValue Value="Amount: 1234"/>
              <SimpleValue Value="Change: 2.0 "/>
              <SimpleValue Value="Total:"*""/>    
           </Names>
        </NameList>
   </Names>
```

I have checked allow wildcards in my Xquery expression, but that does not seem to be working in SoapUI.
Is there a workaround for it?

Note: The response order is inconsistent so cannot use Xpath.
Can read the values from SimpleValue node SimpleVale[1],SimpleValue[5]
but, since it's inconsistent there's no way of knowing which node contains Total.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're only interested in making sure `Value="Total"` is present and you don't care what value it might have, you could use `SimpleValue[contains(@Value, "Total:")]`, which just checks the attribute name. For example:

```
(:  Replace these variables with values extracted from the soapUI response:)
declare variable $date := "MM/DD/Year";
declare variable $name := "John";
declare variable $amount := "1234";
declare variable $change := "2.0";

for $NameList in //<soapUI response payload>//NameList
let  $Names := $NameList/Names
where $Names/SimpleValue[@Value = concat("Date: ", $date)] and 
            $Names/SimpleValue[@Value = concat("Name: ", $name)] and
            $Names/SimpleValue[@Value = concat("Amount: ", $amount)] and
            $Names/SimpleValue[@Value = concat("Change: ", $change)] and
            $Names/SimpleValue[contains(@Value, "Total:")]    
return $NameList
```

You would also need to strip some of those leading and trailing white space characters on the attribute values to make sure you got a good match.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the quotation marks around *. As you have it now, it'll fail because the actual value is "Total: 0.0 " but your expected value is "Total: "0.0" "

Comment: That's the problem! It seems to be a bug in SopaUI itself. Does not work when I try to use * for wildcards. Inside/outside or even without quotations.